# Select and unselect multiple drop down list onchange function using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple selection dropdown list. I am doing that when **All Batches** is select then other selected option will b unselect and when **Batch01** or other option is selected then **All Batches** will be unselect. Here is the code of html

Issue is that when select Batch01 or other option is selected then All Batches will not be unselect

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#batchid").change(function() {
    var batchid = $(this).val();
    var str_bat = batchid.toString();
    if (str_bat.search("All") != -1) {
      $("#batchid option").each(function(i) {
        $('#batchid option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').prop('selected', false);

      });
      $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', true);
      $('select').material_select();
    }

    if (str_bat.search(",") != -1) {
      $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', false);
      var res = str_bat.split("12345678910");
      if (res[0] == 'All') {
        alert(res[0] + ' ' + res[1]);
        $('#batchid option[value=' + res[1] + ']').prop('selected', false);
        $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', true);
        $('select').material_select();
      } else {
        $('#batchid option[value=' + res[1] + ']').prop('selected', true);
        $('#batchid option[value=All]').prop('selected', false);
        $('select').material_select();
      }
    }
  });
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<select id="batchid" data-rel="chosen" name="batchid[]" class="form-control" multiple>
  <option value="All" selected>All Batches</option>
  <option value="1">Batch01</option>
  <option value="2">Batch02</option>
  <option value="3">Batch03</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix the scripts to point at the correct multiselect js file and make the snippet run

Comment: There is an error when running the code snippet